# ERRO AO INSERIR PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, sql-insert

[image: arquivo de conexo]

[image: Ãrquivo de inserir no banco]

não insere informação nenhuma no banco da o erro abaixo:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on
>   null in C:\xampp\htdocs\TELA DE LOGIN\classes\videos.php:11 Stack
>   trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TELA DE LOGIN\php\addGaleria.php(25):
>   Videos->cadastrar('escola_online', '127.0.0.1', 'root', '') #1 {main}
>   thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TELA DE LOGIN\classes\videos.php on line 11

Comment: Os valores estão indo sem Aspas para o banco, não pode ser esse problema? pois são strings

Comment: então coloquei mas mesmo assim, não insere!

Comment: nao da mas o erro porem ainda não insere no banco!!!

Comment: O bindValue é com aspas simples tambem

Comment: faz um debug nele, coloca pra imprimir a string que ele cria com o VAR_DUMP() e coloca na pergunta

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Seguindo o Manual do PHP pode-se ver que o insert com o bindValue se utiliza aspas simples, creio que isso esteja impactando no seu código.
Ficando assim:

```
<?php
  Class videos
  {
     try{

          $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=meuBancoDeDados', $username, $password);
           $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        public function cadastrar($titulo, $thumb, $descricao, $idVid)
        {
       $sql = $pdo-> prepare("INSERT INTO video(titulo, thumb, descricao, embed) VALUES (':t',':th',':d',':vi')");
       $sql->execute(array(
              ':t'=> $titulo,
              ':th' => $thumb,
              ':d' => $descricao,
              ':vi' => $idVid
       ));
      }

       echo $sql->rowCount();
     }
     catch(PDOException $e) {
          echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }
  }   
?>
```

> Eu adicionei uma conexão em PDO pressupondo que tenha feito isso no
>   seu código porém não postou, caso não, o problema pode estar sendo ai

Comment: testei o que me passou tb e não tive sucesso, que estranho tenho a outra que esta funcionando ok essa não vai de jeito nenhum

Comment: Poderia inserir outra colocando afundo o erro que ele mostra? Fazendo um debug comm var_dump e vendo se ele está inserindo realmente o que vpcê deseja e colando no banco pra ver se está tendo um erro de sintaxe ou algo do gênero

Comment: <?php
        Class videos
        {
     try{

          $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=escola_online', $embed, $titulo);
           $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

     public function cadastrar($titulo, $thumb, $descricao, $idVid)
      
     {
       $sql = $pdo-> prepare("INSERT INTO video(titulo, thumb, descricao, embed) VALUES (':t',':th',':d',':vi')");
       $sql->execute(array(
              ':t'=> $titulo,
              ':th' => $thumb,
              ':d' => $descricao,
              ':vi' => $idVid
       ));  }?>

Comment: sou novo com php não consegui debugar, se poder ajudar agradeço muito assim aprendo.

Comment: rafaelsaugo@gmail.com